# AWS Aurora 3x slower than MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

We have this big query (big in variables) which takes around 3s on MsSQL.
We can run this query 100x times and all of them will take 3s.

Using Aurora, the first time the query loads it takes 9s, but then it takes 500ms, which is very nice, but we just can`t wait 9s every first time we run this query. 
Actually, I am not sure how long the cache takes place, but it seems to be around a couple of minutes and then we have to wait 9s again.

I cant say to my clients "I know 9s is too long, but then you will wait just half a second".
They will reply "I just need to see my data once. It doesn't matter to me the 2nd time would be faster. I simply don't get there."

**Simulation:**

**MsSQL**

- 1st time: 3s
- 2nd time: 3s
- 3rd time: 3s
- ... 10 minutes later
- xth time: 3s
- yth time: 3s

**Aurora**

- 1st time: 9s
- 2nd time: 500ms
- 3rd time: 500ms
- ... 10 minutes later
- xth time: 9s
- yth time: 500ms

Is this expected or am I doing something wrong?